# Lisp: can a macro be recursive?

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

I've recently started coding in Lisp, and have already been most impressed with macros - they [allowed me to do complex loop-unrolling](https://www.thanassis.space/score4.html#lisp) at compile-time, something I can't do this elegantly in any other language that I know of (i.e. code-generate while keeping the original structure).

On to optimization: I've sprinkled type annotations (lots of "the fixnum") in the same code. Once I've added 3 or 4 of them, I realized I was doing it wrong - this is what macros are for, Dont Repeat Yourself...

```
; whenever we want to indicate that the result of an operation 
; fits in a fixnum, we macro expand (the fixnum (...))
(defmacro fast (&rest args)
  `(the fixnum ,args))
...
(cond
  (...)
  (t (let* ((forOrange (+ (aref counts 5)
                          (fast * 2 (aref counts 6))
                          (fast * 5 (aref counts 7))
                          (fast * 10 (aref counts 8))))
            (forYellow (+ (aref counts 3)
                          (fast * 2 (aref counts 2))
                          (fast * 5 (aref counts 1))
                          (fast * 10 (aref counts 0))))
```

...and indeed, this worked: instead of writing lots of "(the fixnum (...))" everywhere, I just quickly prefix the expression with "fast" - and all is well.

But then...

I realized that even this is not where things should stop: in principle, the macro "fast" should... be called at the TOP of the evaluation, in this case:

```
            (forYellow (fast + (aref counts 3)
                          (* 2 (aref counts 2))
                          (* 5 (aref counts 1))
                          (* 10 (aref counts 0))))
```

...and it should recursively "plant" "(the fixnum (...))" in all subexpressions.

Can this be done?
Can a "defmacro" be recursive?

**UPDATE**: I faced some really weird problems trying to do this, so I ended up doing what Rord suggested below - i.e. implemented a function, tested it in the repl, and calling it from the macro:

```
(defun operation-p (x)
  (or (equal x '+) (equal x '-) (equal x '*) (equal x '/)))

(defun clone (sexpr)
  (cond
    ((listp sexpr)
     (if (null sexpr)
       ()
       (let ((hd (car sexpr))
             (tl (cdr sexpr)))
         (cond
           ((listp hd) (append (list (clone hd)) (clone tl)))
           ((operation-p hd) (list 'the 'fixnum (cons hd (clone tl))))
           (t (cons hd (clone tl)))))))
    (t sexpr)))

(defmacro fast (&rest sexpr)
  `(,@(clone sexpr)))
```

And it works fine under SBCL:

```
$ sbcl
This is SBCL 1.0.52, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
...
* (load "score4.cl")

T
* (setf a '(+ (1 2) (- 1 (+ 5 6)))
...
* (clone a)

(THE FIXNUM (+ (1 2) (THE FIXNUM (- 1 (THE FIXNUM (+ 5 6))))))

* (macroexpand '(fast + 1 2 THE FIXNUM (- 1 THE FIXNUM (+ 5 6))))

(THE FIXNUM (+ 1 2 THE FIXNUM (THE FIXNUM (- 1 THE FIXNUM (THE FIXNUM (+ 5 6))))))
T
```

All is well, except for one side-effect: CMUCL works, but no longer compiles the code:

```
; Error: (during macroexpansion)
; Error in KERNEL:%COERCE-TO-FUNCTION:  the function CLONE is undefined.
```

Oh well :-)

**UPDATE**: The compilation failure was addressed and solved in [a different SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138714/solved-lisp-macro-calling-a-function-works-in-interpreter-fails-in-compiler).

Comment: A style suggestion: Don't splice the form to be transformed into the macro call.  Keep it as a subform, i.e. prefer `(fast (* ...))` over `(fast * ...)`.  It makes the semantics simpler (consider the case `(fast 3)`—what is the meaning of this form supposed to be?) and caters to the reader's expectations about the structure of forms.

Comment: @Matthias: Initially I had it like that - but I realized that in this case there are unambiguous semantics (i.e. "(fast 3)" can only mean "3") and... it makes it easier to use: you see a place in the code you want casts to fixnum, you don't have to hunt for paren-matching: just type "fast" in front.

Comment: This is quite common in Scheme.

Comment: @leppie Right.  There is even built-in precedent for it, like `map`: `(map bling xs)`.  But note that this is not true for CL, where you have to write `(mapcar #'bling xs)`.  The reason for the difference is that Scheme is a Lisp-1, so there is no confusion about what `bling` means.  In CL, when I see `bling` in a non-operator position, I assume it's the *variable* `bling`.  Hence my warning of what I believe contradicts the reader's expectations.

Comment: @ttsiodras Having to hunt for parens when enclosing a form in a call means you're not using a good enough editor. ;)  With paredit, try `C-1 (`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A macro is not just called, but expanded when it is used, so referring to a macro in its own definition can get messy. But you don't have to do that: macros can call regular functions, so you can write a regular function to do the recursive list processing, and then just use that from the macro.

Comment: I did as you suggested (updated the question above with my solution). My problem now is that even though it runs, this code can't be compiled with CMUCL: (compile-file "bug.cl") fails... Opening new SO question for this.

Comment: Compilation issue solved in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138714/solved-lisp-macro-calling-a-function-works-in-interpreter-fails-in-compiler

Comment: actually. referring to a macro in its own definition is perfectly fine. in fact, this is the way `cond` is implemented

Comment: @erjoalgo: I didn't mean to suggest that it can't work, but that it is harder to reason about than regular recursive functions.

Comment: actually, in many cases it is the most natural way to reason about macros with a regular, expanding structure, like @Kaz points out in his answer

Comment: Calling a function from a macro isn't always an option. Often you write a macro instead of a function because you want to mutate an argument, for instance. Functions can't do that. See @Kaz's answer for a better solution.

Comment: @SodAlmighty That doesn't really make sense. In case of your example, you can just as well produce the expansion that mutates an argument from within a function as you can directly within the macro. (And to be precise, the macro itself cannot mutate a variable given as an argument to the macro call because it doesn't exist yet at macro expansion time – only the expansion produced by the macro can.)

Comment: Ah...you mean the function can produce a list like `(setf x some-operation)`, return that to the macro, and then the macro just returns that? You know, that never occurred to me. Wouldn't it get evaluated between being returned from the function and returned from the macro, though? (I still don't fully understand exactly when and where evaluation takes place.)

Comment: @SodAlmighty No, a macro expansion is just a list of symbols (and other values). There's no reason any of it would get evaluated unless you either specifically ask Lisp to do that (e.g. with `eval`) or until the code produced by the macro expansion actually gets executed.

Comment: I am continually surprised by both the complexity and the simplicity of lisp. It is truly a unique language. And a brain-melting dichotomy.

Answer (score 10):

**You can definitely write a macro which uses itself in its own expansion.** This makes perfect sense, and it is a natural way to write the COND macro, which has a regular, expanding structure due to the arbitrarily long list of cond pairs, that can be expressed by the usual car/cdr or first/rest recursion.

```
(defmacro new-cond (&rest cond-pairs)
  (cond      ;; you need cond to compile new-cond syntax, LOL!
    ((null cond-pairs) nil)
    ((atom cond-pairs) (error "new-cond: bad syntax!"))
    (t `(if ,(first (first cond-pairs))
           (progn ,@(rest (first cond-pairs)))
           (new-cond ,@(rest cond-pairs))))))


> (macroexpand-1 '(new-cond (1 2) (3 4)))

(IF 1 (PROGN 2) (NEW-COND (3 4)))
```

This is very analogous to lazy list processing. `macroexpand` expands just the outer macro, leaving a "promise" object to continue the expansion. That "promise" object is the macro call `(NEW-COND (3 4))` at the tail.

Of course the real macro expander will walk the whole form and "force" all these promises (unexpanded macro calls) until no more remain.

I think there are some advantages to this style, such as easy debugging with `macroexpand`. You get a small expansion. If its recursive nature is obvious, that's a win. If the macro is such that your brain needs to see the whole thing expanded, it's a loss.

Here, I can see that `(IF 1 (PROGN 2) (NEW-COND (3 4)))` is the correct compile. If 1 is true, evaluate the forms list (2). Otherwise keep going with the other cond pairs. Now we have to verify the one pair case:

```
> (macroexpand-1 '(new-cond (3 4)))
(IF 3 (PROGN 4) (NEW-COND))
```

Excellent, and the no-pair case `(NEW-COND)`, by obvious inspection, reduces to nil.

**Secondly, a macro can also invoke itself in its own code.** So, for instance, if we are Lisp implementors trying to define `cond`, there is a way we can actually get away with:

```
(defmacro cond (&rest cond-pairs)
  (cond      ;; you need cond to compile new-cond syntax, LOL!
    ((null cond-pairs) nil)
    ((atom cond-pairs) (error "new-cond: bad syntax!"))
    (t `(if ,(first (first cond-pairs))
           (progn ,@(rest (first cond-pairs)))
           (new-cond ,@(rest cond-pairs))))))
```

How can `cond` be **used** in a macro which is defining it? The answer is bootstrapping. The `cond` being expanded in the macro is an existing `cond` that we somehow already have. This new definition expands just fine with that existing `cond`, and then replaces it.

This process can be repeated. We can evaluate the above `defmacro` form again and again; the `cond` which the previous evaluation has just installed is used for expanding the `cond` which occurs in the new evaluation.

If we are boostrapping one Lisp compiler with an existing one, we may be able to start this process using the host Lisp's `cond`, so we never require a second, boostrapping version of the `cond` macro that doesn't rely on `cond`.

Note that for this to work, the body of our replacement `cond` macro has to be fully expanded before being installed as the new definition of `cond`. This cannot work if the bodies of macro definitions are left unexpanded; then it becomes a recursive call. In other words, this isn't recursion. Recursion cannot work; a macro cannot need itself to expand itself. At best it can need an existing macro which is not itself, but which happens to have the same name.

Comment: You can lose cond inside new-cond if you use nested if. `(if (null cond-pairs) nil (if (atom cond-pairs) (error "new-cond: bad syntax!") '(if ,(first ...` (before if should be `)

Comment: @jcubic That would indeed be necessary if we were actually defining `cond`, having only `if`.

Answer (score 6):

Sure.  You can write a macro that recursively *walks* the argument forms and transforms them the way you want, one subform at a time.  Since this is slightly more complicated than it sounds, the right way to do it is to use a library for *code walking*.

[Quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/) includes `hu.dwim.walker`, which is apparently an improved version of the [arnesi](http://common-lisp.net/project/bese/arnesi.html) code walker.