# Macro calling a function works in interpreter, fails in compiler (SBCL + CMUCL)

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

As suggested in [a macro-related question I recently posted to SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115097/lisp-can-a-macro-be-recursive/), I coded a macro called "fast" via a  call to a function [(here is the standalone code in pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/ZXrNtjxJ):

```
(defun main ()
  (progn
    (format t "~A~%" (+ 1 2 (* 3 4) (+ 5 (- 8 6))))
    (format t "~A~%" (fast (+ 1 2 (* 3 4) (+ 5 (- 8 6)))))))
```

This works in the REPL, under both SBCL and CMUCL:

```
$ sbcl
This is SBCL 1.0.52, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
...
* (load "bug.cl")
22
22

$
```

Unfortunately, however, the code no longer compiles:

```
$ sbcl
This is SBCL 1.0.52, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
...
* (compile-file "bug.cl")
...
;   during macroexpansion of (FAST (+ 1 2 ...)). Use *BREAK-ON-SIGNALS* to
;   intercept:
;
;    The function COMMON-LISP-USER::CLONE is undefined.
```

So it seems that by having my macro "fast" call functions ("clone","operation-p") at compile-time, I trigger issues in Lisp compilers (verified in both CMUCL and SBCL).

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong and/or how to fix this?

Comment: maybe put the answer in an answer, and then accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some remarks about your code.

- multiple tests of an object for equality can be replaced by `MEMBER`
- backquote with a following comma does nothing. You can just remove that.
- you can ensure that your functions are available for a macro by a) moving these functions to an additional file and compile/load that before use of the macro, by b) using `EVAL-WHEN`to inform the compiler to evaluate the definition of the functions or by c) adding the functions to the macro as local functions

Example:

```
(defmacro fast (&rest sexpr)
  (labels ((operation-p (x)
             (member x '(+ - * /)))
           (clone (sexpr)
             (if (consp sexpr)
                 (destructuring-bind (head . tail) sexpr
                   (if (operation-p head)
                       `(the fixnum (,head ,@(clone tail)))
                     (cons (clone head) (clone tail))))
               sexpr)))
    (car (clone sexpr))))
```

Note that this and your version of `FAST` are not complete code walkers. They recognize only simple function calls (and not the other Lisp constructs like LAMBDA, LET, FLET, LABELS, etc.).

Comment: I am new to LISP, and your code shows many things I didn't know - thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, I figured it out: I had to move the functions invoked by the macro (and therefore required during compilation) in a separate file, "compile-file" it first, "load" it, then "compile-file" the one with the macro.

Comment: compiling the file with the functions is not enough. you also need to load it.

Comment: Indeed, you are right - I did that obviously, but forgot to write it down.

Answer (score 1):

Macro-expansion tie happens (typically) during compile time.

That means that any functions used during the macro expansion (note, not necessarily *in* the macro-expansion, the return value as it were) must be defined when the macro is encountered during compilation.